# Saving SQLite to Documents Folder

Tags: sqlite, blackberry-webworks, blackberry-playbook

I need to pick an underlying method of saving data collected in the field (offline and remote locations).  I want to use the HTML5 Database with SQLite but I can I pick the location?  So far, I haven't been able to accomplish that.  Here is some sample code I was using:

```
var dbName = "";

var Dir = blackberry.io.dir;
var path = Dir.appDirs.shared.documents.path;
dbName = path + "/" + "databasetest.db";  

var db = openDatabase(dbName, '1.0', 'Test', 50 * 1024);
```

I used an "alert()" to see the file was "supposedly" created, but when I opened the folder in Explorer I cannot find it.  Not really sure why and hense my question.

My application is for data entry, without getting into specifics, user may end up collecting a lot or little data.  But I want some way of downloading the SQLite database?

Is this the intention of the SQLite database, or will I have to use another solution?

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

The [Web SQL Database specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/) was designed for browsers where it would not have been appropriate to allow web pages to access arbitrary file paths.

The intended way to download data is to upload it to a web server in the cloud.

If you want to know the file name of your database, try executing the [`PRAGMA database_list`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_database_list). (Whether your app can access that path is a different question.)